# EXCEL PROGRESS BAR STUCK

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have code that it has been running good for months. Lately I started getting the following error:

Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)

I have a progress bar also. I noticed that the progress bar is stuck and ever since I am getting the Error 91.

This is the code for the progress bar:

```
    Sub PROGRESS()
    Dim x               As Integer
    Dim MyTimer         As Double

    Dim appIE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim item_data As Object


 For k = 6 To 15 Step 1

  Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & k - 5 & " of 10: " & Format((k - 5) 
  / 10, "0%")


    s = 1
    H = 1
    L = 1
    StopLoop = 0
    q = Format(k, "0")
    If IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("$E$" & q).Value) = True Then


     With appIE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=" & Sheets("Up Trend 
     Stocks").Range("$A$" & q).Value
    Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set html = .document
       End With

     Set item_data = html.querySelector(".pr span")
     Range("$B$" & q).Value = item_data.innerText

   End If

    Next

    appIE.Quit
   Range("D1").Select

   Application.StatusBar = False


      End Sub
```

Error is generated and this line of code:

```
 Range("$B$" & q).Value = item_data.innerText
```

Please let if I can provide further details.

Thanks

Comment: You should double-check all the hard-coded values are still correct. Particularly, `"https://finance.google.com/finance?q="` and `".pr span"`. Also, maybe check that the hard-coded ranges are still accurate for the workbook(s).

Comment: Hello - I checked - Everything is the same as before. I am not sure what s causing this.

What can we do to further debug this?

Thank you,

Comment: The error message you're getting, is often caused by the object not be properly assigned. I suspect, from the error, that at that line in the code, `item_data is Nothing`. Do you know how to check that with either breakpoints or debug statements?

Comment: Hi - No Not really...This is frustrating, it was working fine and did not touch the code at all.

Comment: For breakpoints, when you're in the code editor, if you put your mouse cursor in a line of code (such as the one creating the error) and press `F9`, it will toggle the breakpoint -- set one if there isn't one there already, or take it off. You can also set or takeoff breakpoints by clicking to the left of the line of code, in the grey column area. **Note:** breakpoints can't be set on declarations -- whether of variables or subs or functions. When the code execution reaches the breakpoint, it'll pause automatically.

Comment: For the first breakpoint check, you could also just run the code, and then press debug when it errors. Then, you can look at the items assigned to local variables in the locals window. (If that's closed, you can open it by going into < view -- locals > along the top tab strip.)

Comment: I believe you are right, item_data is set to nothing. Why is that? Havent changed anything in my code.

Comment: One possible reason, `html.querySelector(".pr span")` does not return anything _to be_ assigned to `item_data`. Another reason, `html is Nothing`. Easiest to check is if `html` is set to `Nothing`. You can probably check that at the same breakpoint location.

Comment: Did you have an update to Internet Explorer since the last time this code worked fine?

Comment: Hello - This is what I found. This code reads stock prices from Google Finance page. It seems the Google Finance page has changed and I can no longer read the data I need. I believe I have to to find a different website from where I can the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the reason for this error. It has nothing to do with the code itself, but the problem lies in the webpage from which I am extracting the data.
This code reads stock prices from Google Finance page. It seems the Google Finance page has changed and I can no longer read the data I need.